# How to list all files in specific path in firebase storage in pyrbase?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, pyrebase

I want to list all the files in specific path in firebase storage using `pyrebase4`.

I found some question about this topic but not the same because most of the question is about list all the files in the storage in general not in given path like the following code:

```py
name_list = storage.list_files()
    for file in name_list:
        print(file.name)
```

As I said this will list all the files but this will problem if we have big storage with a lot of files.

Also I know I can do this programmatically but this will took long time if the storage big.

Comment: your link is not related to my question